# Objective-C send special character POST

Tags: php, objective-c, forms, http-post, urlencode

I have create a application that send two POST parameter to my file PHP and it's save data in my database.

The code into xcode project that send parameter is:

```
NSString *post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"&key1=%@&key2=%@", myString1, myString2];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mysite.com/test.php"]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

The code into my file PHP that save data into my database is:

```
$val1 = $_POST['key1'];
$val2 = $_POST['key2'];
$val1 = urldecode($val1);
$val2 = urldecode($val2);

$sql = "INSERT INTO test(nome, cognome) VALUES ('$val1', '$val2')";
mysql_query($sql);
```

The problem is that if I insert a parameter that contains special character (for example `é` or `ä`), my program save into database normal character (`e` and `a`).

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
```

The problem here is that you're using ASCII, but ASCII doesn't contain é, ä, etc. You should be using Unicode instead. Try switching `NSASCIIStringEncoding` for `NSUTF8StringEncoding` in the code above.